# R internals: extracting a function pointer from an SEXP object

Tags: c++, c, r

Is there a way to extract a C-style function pointer from an SEXP object?

The [Writing R Extensions zero-finding example](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Zero_002dfinding) is almost what I want. The body of `f.check` is passed from R to C and then called with `eval`. Since I'm working inside CUDA, I can't call `eval` on an SEXP object in this way or use the `Function` type in `Rcpp` directly. I have to unpack the raw function pointer inside the SEXP and pass it to a CUDA kernel.

Comment: I must be confused. You want a pointer to an R function, but I don't see how that would be very useful inside your GPU.

Comment: I just realized that pointing to an R closure probably wouldn't work, but if there were some way to extract the C++ function pointer from the output of `Rcpp::cppFunction`, that might be better. My overall goal is just to specify a function in R and then evaluate it inside a CUDA kernel.

Answer (score 1):

GPUs can only run kernels consisting of code specifically designed for the architecture. I know very little about CUDA, but I think the principles are the same as OpenCL, which is pretty much C with an API for dealing with GPU memory and parallel architecture. You can't just run R or C++ code in the GPU. All the pointer is going to give you is a number stuck in the GPU. You can't call functions in main memory from the GPU.